# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Tags: java, spring, list, jpa, transactional

I am getting the following error when I try to implement my `query` below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token
```

My query is within a Spring data `PersonRepository` that extends `CrudRepository`

**Query:**

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("DELETE (entity) FROM Person entity WHERE entity.id = :id")
List<Person> deleteFromPersonWithId(@Param("id") String id);
```

What is the error in my syntax?

Comment: It should be entity.id in place of person.id in the where clause

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I do have entity.id

Comment: ok and you don't need entity in the brackets for delete

Comment: Write like this `DELETE FROM Person WHERE id = :id`. But better use `entityManager.remove(entity)` syntax because this also removes associated instances

Comment: How do I create an entity manager in sping?

Comment: So your JPQL is wrong, so look at a reference for JPQL syntax and correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a right syntax of DELETE query, it should look like this.

```
DELETE FROM Person entity WHERE entity.id = :id
```

By the way there is a [delete](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#delete-T-) method which does exactly what you want in the `CrudRepository` itself. So no need to duplicate it.

Comment: Is this a native query then?

Comment: No, it's JPQL query.

Comment: Just call the method `delete` on the instance of implementation of this interface and pass your entity object into it. That should do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

Query must be:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM Person entity WHERE entity.id = :id")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
entityManager.remove(entityInstance)
```

will remove entity from DB when transaction is committed.

Answer (score 0):

Change your annotations as such;

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("DELETE FROM Person WHERE id = :id")
void deleteFromPersonWithId(@Param("id") String id);
```

Comment: Getting error: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations

Comment: Probably hibernate is calling a query.list() statement, as you're trying to return a List<Person>, which is not possible from a delete statement. Replace the return type by void.